# Source files constantly getting appended with garbage when saving on USB drive/stick

Tags: usb

I'm a hardware/software developer and prefer to keep my source files on an external USB drive or thumbdrive. The problem I've been facing for years it seems is when I try to save these files. When I save a file and then compile I occasionally get syntax errors on lines that don't even exist in my source. For example it will complain about line 83 when my source file is only 80 lines long. Lets say I have the file open in a particular editor (I prefer Programmers Notepad or Notepad++) and see only 80 lines... I can save but then if I pop open the same file in parallel using something like Wordpad sure enough... I see the extra lines and it looks like the last few lines of real code got munged and then appended to the end of the file.

At first I thought it was the editor but have found that no matter what editor I use it happens fairly frequently. I recently upgraded to a new laptop and OS (From Win7 to Win10) and lo and behold the same problem exists here. Tried different USB drives/sticks.... same deal.  Am I missing something???  This problem has been driving me bonkers! :P